# Discord.js get array of attachments with certain filetype

Tags: node.js, arrays, discord.js, attachment

So I'm currently working on a discordbot that should scan attachments for certain filetypes and filter them out. Playing around a litte bit, It currently looks like this:

```
message.attachments.forEach(attachment => {
    validateFunction(attachment, message)

function validateFunction(attachment, message) {
if (!attachment.contentType.includes('image/')) {
    message.delete().catch((error) => {return});
```

And while it does its job for now (in this case deleting everything that isn't an image) its not quite how I'd like it to be and a lot more unflexible than I need it...

what I'd rather like to do is to create an array that, for example, contains every attachment that isn't an image file so i could just make an "if array.size > 0 => message.delete", removing the for each, keeping everything in one function and giving me a lot more flexibility to do things like for example a logmessage containing the number of found attachments in the array and such things.

but I struggle to get the attachments filtered out like this by filetypes, so...

does anyone have any idea how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can partition the collection. Doing so will split the collection into 2 unique arrays based on whether they satisfy the supplied expression.

```js
const [images, nonImages] = message.attachments
   .partition(a => a.contentType.includes('image/'));
```

[Collections - Extra Utilities](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/collections.html#extra-utilities)

Answer (score 0):

Just because i was also looking for this as an answer too, i have implemented a function that i think might help others too to validate file types.

```
/** 
@param files Collection
@param match Array|String
*/
const validateFiles = (files, match) => {
  let [matched, notMatched] = files.partition(a => {
    if (Array.isArray(match)) {
      let found = [];
      match.forEach(m => {
        if (a.contentType !== null && a.contentType.includes(m)) {
          found.push(m)
        }
      })
      return found.length > 0;
    } else {
      return (a.contentType !== null && a.contentType.includes(match))
    }
  })
  return {
    found: matched,
    ignore: notMatched
  }
}


let validate = validateFiles(message.attachments, 'image/');
if (validate.ignore.size > 0) {
    message.delete();
}

let validate = validateFiles(message.attachments, ['image/', 'audio/', 'video/']);
if (validate.ignore.size > 0) {
    message.delete();
}
```

This function has helped me a lot so hopefully it will help others.